# Source Safe branch differences

Tags: diff, branch, visual-sourcesafe, utility

I am trying to generate a meaningful report showing the differences between two branches in Visual Source Safe. The built-in visual tool is quite helpful but the generated report is absolutely useless.

Does anyone know of any tools or utilities which can help in this regard.

(And yes I have tried Google but to no avail).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ECMerge can do that (NB: I work for ECMerge). It should detect your VSS installation by itself. Then you need to give it the root folder of your VSS repository as you would for a local folder (see SCC Source in the Side menu) and the paths to the branches within. It will output folders reports, patches and/or individual HTML file comparison reports.